# Master-Detail Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, master-detail

I am trying to implement simple master detail databinding C# WPF in Xaml. On the left side I have a listbox which is properly generated and on the right side I have a datagrid. When I click on left listbox I want my Datagrid to change accordingly. Currently I belive I have problem wtih SelectedItem path. Could someone give an advice?

```
public class Pipe
{
    public string ID { get; set; } 

    public ObservableCollection<Node> nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>(); 
}

public class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }    
}

ObservableCollection<Pipe>  p = new ObservableCollection<Pipe>();
```

After populating my Pipe Class I bind it via

```
lstLines.DisplayMemberPath = "ID";
lstLines.ItemsSource = p;
```

Until now everything work correctly.
Next in Xaml I bind my datagrid to the SelectedItem of Listbox via :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.nodes, ElementName=lstLines, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}
```

Here is the problem .... I cant find the correct path so my datagrid is populated base on selecteditem of list. I've tried several variations but without lack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Path` is fine but you can bind only `public` properties and your `nodes` is a field:

```
public ObservableCollection<Node> nodes {get; set; }
```

you can initialize `nodes` in the `Pipe` constructor, but it must be a property

Comment: I feel so stupido :) I,ve modified my code to : ObservableCollection<Node> _nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get { return _nodes; } }. And it works fine